# Consulta mysql retornar 4 counts mesma tabela

Tags: mysql

Eu gostaria de fazer um select na mesma tabela que conte 4 valores diferentes, todos com clausulas, estou tentando da seguinte maneira mas não estou conseguindo, quero que cada count seja feito em um STATUS onde eu especifico ali, mas ele não está me retornando nada, onde estou errando?

```
SELECT count(id) as new AND status IN ('pgto_confirmado', 'pending'), count(id) as fup AND status IN ('processing'), count(id) as ce AND status IN('confirmar_entrega'), count(id) as complete AND status IN ('complete', 'repassado') 
FROM sgn_tbd_pedido 
WHERE data_entregar LIKE '%2018-03-08%' 
GROUP BY cidade;
```

Gostaria que retornasse por exemplo:

> ```
> Cidade  NEW  FUP  CE  COMPLETE
> Campinas 19  11   5     100
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A estrutura do [`CASE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp) é um pouco diferente no `mysql`; tente o código abaixo:

```
SELECT 
    sum (CASE status WHEN 'pgto_confirmado' THEN 1 WHEN 'pending' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as new
    sum (CASE status WHEN 'processing' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as fup,
    sum (CASE status WHEN 'confirmar_entrega' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ce,
    sum (CASE status WHEN 'complete' THEN 1 WHEN 'repassado' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as complete
FROM sgn_tbd_pedido 
WHERE data_entregar LIKE '%2018-03-08%' 
GROUP BY cidade;
```

Comment: Tentei e me retornou isso

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') as new, count (CASE status WHEN 'processing' THEN 1 ELSE 0) as fup, count (CAS' at line 1)`

Comment: sera que precisa especificar o `as new` ou somente `new`?

Comment: Adicionei um `END` no final do `THEN 1 ELSE 0` e me retornou `ERROR 1630 (42000): FUNCTION db_op.count does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual`

Comment: fiz uma mudança na resposta.. primeiro troquei o `count` pelo `sum`, estava mesmo errado; também adicionei `end`aos `cases`. Agora deveria funcionar

Comment: Esse funcionou melhor para mim, já está com os cases montados corretamente.

Answer (score 3):

você pode usuar o  CASE com funções agregadas. esse é um  exemplo que pode funcionar na maioria dos  SGDB:

```
select campo_id,
    count(*) total,
    sum(case when algumCampo = 'valoresperado' then 1 else 0 end) toal1,
    sum(case when algumCampo = 'outrovalor' then 1 else 0 end) toal12,
from suaTabela
group by cidade
```

Ai você pode personalizar da froma que achar necessária, para mais informações 
consulte o  **SUM case**

Comment: Nesse count(*) total, ele irá me retornar todos os valores somados? em um número só?

Comment: No  caso o  Count(*) retorna  todos os registros da tabela
o sum retorna todos os que vc epsecificou atravez do  seu predicate